# How can I get a Samsung Galaxy S6 self-compiled kernel to boot?

Tags: android, kernel

I downloaded everything I needed to compile the kernel. I compile it using `make ARCH=arm64 exynos7420-zerofltespr_defconfig` followed by `make ARCH=arm64`

Aside from warnings, there is nothing stopping the kernel from finishing compiling. It generates the "Image" file inside the arch/arm64/boot directory.

But when replacing the extracted zImage from my stock boot.img, and repacking, it never boots and just sits at the "Samsung" screen.

I really don't get what I am missing considering the code is completely untouched.

Thanks all!

EDIT: I used someone elses boot.img, unpacked it, replaced their zImage with mine, repacked the boot.img, and lo and behold. It boot up. Why did the stock boot.img not work? I really am not just satisfied with "it working" i would love to know the reason for it.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer for anyone wanting to know:

remove the following from the fstab file inside the ramdisk:

`support_scfs,verify`

Boots perfectly now :D